# Android SQLite DB Inserting into field with values that include dash/"-"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert into my SQLiteDB a value that has a "-" and SQL doesn't like.

I cannot modify the value or replace the "-" with some other characters as it's a Firebase key I use to query for other things in Firebase.

How do I get around it? Thanks.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "0aa684ba" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO favouriteUsers (userId) VALUES (0aa684ba-05c9-4e76-b6a0-4fd10bbcd958)
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). In your sepcific case, you didn't quote that value, so your `values` field is not a single UUID, it's a mathematical subtraction expression: `0aa684ba MINUS 05c9 MINUS 4e76 etc...`, and none of those "values" are valid field names either, or valid numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I learned about SQL injection in web dev, but I figure I get go the lazy way since the db for my app is internal to the system. But yes, I will get into a habit of using ?. Cheers.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's in internal-only data. You can still quite easily inject yourself. e.g. `name = "Miles O'Brien"; sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('" + name + "')";` 'external' doesn't mean external to your system, it means "external to the query string", so ANYTHING you put into a query string can conceivably introduce an sql syntax error (at best), or completely subvert the meaning/execution of the query (worst case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals in SQL go in `'single quotes'`.

Better yet, use `?` literal placeholders and bind the values.